# Embedding dynamic script when page scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to add an iframe which consist of form . I am inserting this iframe when the page is loaded already and scrolled at some position ,I have used jquery this script is working fine it appending that script tag  under that div but the thing it should load iframe at that place.  please help out

**please point out whats wrong in this question**

> i found that iframe is generated by script its not loaded first itself

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element_position = $('#Banner').offset().top;

  $(window).one('scroll', function() {
   

    if (y_scroll_pos < 300) {
      //do stuff
      $('#form1').load("http://www.samisite.com/test-csb2nf/ifform/somejsthatgenrateiframe");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="Banner"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-in">
  <script id="form1"></script>
```

Comment: You are trying to load html into a script tag.

Comment: Please understand what you are trying to do. Is it load content into an iframe? Insert conent via ajax, or dynamically load a script.

Comment: I have a script that dynamically generate iframe. This script I want to load on scroll

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong here...

`$('#Banner').offset().top;` will return undefined - see html fix below

`var scroll_pos_test = element_position;` is just duplication - just use `element_position`

`if (y_scroll_pos > scroll_pos_test)` will not run since y_scroll_pos is undefined

`$('#form1').append('<script src= "http://www.samisite.com/test-csb2nf/ifform/ssform.php"><script>);`

- You are putting a script tag within a script tag. If this works all it is the browser being kind to you.
- Your src attribute is a page, not a script.
- You are also missing a closing single quote.

`<div id="#Banner"></div>` remove the '#' from id.

`<script id="form1"></script>` You say you're trying to load an iframe, so use an iframe not a script.

`</div>` Your example needs a closing div.

So after all that here I think is your solution:

```
<div id="Banner"></div>    <!--corrected id-->
    <div class="form-in" style="height:1500px;"> <!--added height to easily scroll-->
        <iframe id="form1"></iframe> <!--use an iframe-->
    </div>

    <!--keep your scripts organised at the bottom of page-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var element_position = $('#Banner').offset().top;

            $(window).on('scroll', function() {
                var y_scroll_pos = window.pageYOffset;
                if (y_scroll_pos > element_position) {

                    $('#form1').prop({ //'#form1 is now an iframe
                        'src': 'http://www.samisite.com/test-csb2nf/ifform/ssform.php',
                        'height' : '500', 
                        'width' : '100%' //make sure the height and width are enough to display the page
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Now after all that you may get an error in developer console **Blocked loading mixed active content “http://www.samisite.com/test-csb2nf/ifform/ssform.php”**
In that case your iframe content is being blocked by the the browser because that page is loaded over http:// and you are running on a site served over https://. More info can be found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Mixed_content

Answer (score 0):

Just see this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qmad1uLo

There were follwoing mistakes in your code.

1. You've used `#` in the id attribute, which is invalid
2. You're appending the script tag inside another script tag, which is not allowed.

The main problem is that maybe you're running your main site on `https` but the frame is loaded on `http`, so what can you do is that, run your website on http or try to load the iframe on https if possible, then try the above fiddle, it should work like charm.

Comment: hey my actual problem is i have a embed code which is script tag ,

Comment: i want it to load only when i scroll . the code above after correcting , is working but the embeded form is not loading

Answer (score 0):

Use lazyload! I suggest you this one that supports iframes: https://apoorv.pro/lozad.js/